# Configure Laravel to not cache anything in dev environment?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way I can tell Laravel to not cache anything (routes, RouteServiceProvider, config etc.) in my dev environment?

Comment: It only caches stuff if you explicitly run `php artisan route:cache` or `php artisan config:cache`. Otherwise nothing is cached.

Comment: According to the documentation (http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/cache), you can configure your cache settings in `config/cache.php`

Comment: Nah, in my case, I did a fresh install and then when I edited my RouteServiceProvider, the changes wouldn't reflect until I ran `php artisan clear-compiled`, so the caching does seem to be happening without me running any commands.

Comment: @richerlariviere but that only allows you to configure the cache drivers, not individual components that Laravel itself caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did a fresh install and then when I edited my RouteServiceProvider, the changes wouldn't reflect until I ran php artisan clear-compiled, so the caching does seem to be happening without me running any commands.

This issue is fixed via https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/3398 and available for 5.1